# Runing PSConfig.exe via powershell

Tags: powershell, psconfig

I keep getting syntax error for the following psconfig.exe. Any idea?

```
Start-Process "PSConfig.exe" ps-ArgumentList "-cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures" -wait
```

Error: Start-Process : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent
-install -cmd installfeatures'.

Comment: Try this directly...PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b -force -cmd applicationcontent -install -cmd installfeatures

Comment: Cool. It took the command and now going through config process. Thanks Ransher...

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 3):

From your command, looks like their is some error.You have to provide the complete path of PSConfig and also use **-ArgumentList** instead of **ps-ArgumentList**.

```
Start-Process "path of file\PSConfig.exe" -ArgumentList "-cmd upgrade -inplace v2v -passphrase FarmPassPhrase -force -wait" -Wait
```

If their is not such requirement then you can directly run the psconfig and see if that work.

Comment: The parameter name "-ArgumentList" is optional.  You don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try wrapping `PSConfig` in the [MS Crescendo Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/utility-modules/crescendo/overview?view=ps-modules) as in this module at PS Gallery.

[PS Gallery - PSConfig.Crescendo](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSConfig.Crescendo)

To patch a SharePoint server, then it would be a simple matter of

```
Install-Module -Name PSConfig.Crescendo

Invoke-PSConfigSafeProductUpgrade
```

The verbose output process of the MS Crescendo Framework is somewhat limited though in my opinion.